# how to restrict save as popup window without browser closing from all browser by jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, popup

how to remove save as popup window from chrome , Mozilla, explore  etc... by js Event  ?
i was try for closed save as popup window by jQuery Event  on key-event and its working but create one problem that also chrome browser automatically closing.

how to solve " automatically close  or restrict save as popup window without browser close " For my safe code....?

----------------Or-----------------

Any Encryption and decryption Method or software with key for my code .
also, encryption code support all browser

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, however I can tell you that it's not possible to use JS code to stop browser level modal windows from appearing.

Comment: Thanks for comment. It is possible . But i not know how to possible ?

Comment: In chrome browser ,  right side top corner three dots (customized and control Google chrome Menu) - click - find More Tools - click - find option  Save as page - click .  My Question is : " How to auto restrict save as popup  window in chrome browser  by JQuery or any way?"

Comment: As I mentioned above, that's not possible

Comment: It is possible of save as popup closed with browser but  i haven't solution without closing browser  restrict  save as popup window ?

Comment: I have no idea what that is supposed to mean, but I'll say again, for the third and last time, you cannot change the dialogs opened by the browser from JS code. Good luck.

Comment: restrict save as popup window when i use 'window .closed()', but as well as closing browser at a time  . which solution for closing save as popup window  without  browser closing

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking cannot be done by client side coding. Unless you are planning to write your own browser plugin, which has the ability and permission levels to get this done.

Comment: In chrome browser , right side top corner three dots (customized and control Google chrome Menu) - click - find More Tools - click - find option Save as page - click . My Question is : " How to auto restrict save as popup window in chrome browser by JQuery or any way?"

Comment: That three dot controller is a browser controller. It's not in the DOM context which JavaScript or jQuery can access. to access browser level controls, you need to write a browser plugin.

Comment: Thanks . can you guide me for browser plugin ? and How to restrict browser control ?

Comment: got through the official documentation. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: This link provide how to create extension but whenever any user visit my site page that time don't save my web page ? so, i doing restrict save as  popup window  by jQuery coding and this jQuery code write in my web page